# how to calculate scale factor between 2 NON-SIMILAR rectangles

Tags: ios, image, dictionary, scale

Hope somebody can help me :)

I'm trying to scale a point from a map (Latitude, Longitude) to an image (x, y).
For that i need to find the scale factor between the 2 NON-SIMILAR rectangles (i think).

I'll clarify, let's say:

Rectangle 1: A(40.0, 50.0) B(40.0, 56.0) C(43.0, 56.0) D(43.0, 50.0)

(Latitude Delta = 3, Longitude Delta = 6).

Rectangle 2: E(0, 0) F(500, 0) G(500, 300) H(0, 300)

(X Delta = 500, Y Delta = 300).

How can i scale a point P(41.5, 52.5) from rectangle 1 to point (x, y) on rectangle 2?

**UPDATE:**

General idea:

I'm trying to display the user current location (Lat, Lon) on a custom image (not a map image, a drawing of my own) therefor i can't use maps (MKMapKit, Google, Tom-Tom).

I have the user current location (via CoreLocation) and an image (800x460).

The area that i'm mapping is small so i don't need to worry about the earth's curve.

I'm trying to find a formula that'll help me scale my user (Lat, Lon) location into my image (on my iPhone screen)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, you need to find the scale from rect1 to rect2 and then multiply your point with that scale. Since the rectangles are not similar , I think you  will have to find the largest rectangle similar with rect1 that will fit in rect2. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks George!
Still, I know such a formula exists, 
I just can't find/remember it.

Comment: See my answer to get the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , getting the rectangle that is similar with the first one but fits in the second one is not hard. Here's how:

```
CGRect rect1, rect2; //your rectangles.
float scale = MIN(rect1.size.width / rect2.size.width , rect1.size.height / rect2.size.height);
CGRect resultedRect;
resultedRect.origin = rect2.origin;
resultedRect.size = CGSizeMake(rect2.size.width * scale, rect2.size.height * scale); 
//resultedRect is similar with rect1 but fits in rect2. You can now multiply your point with "scale" and get the new position.
```

I'm not sure this is what you are trying to achieve.

Regards,

George

Comment: Hey George!
Thanks for the code! I've tried it.
Unfortunately as i suspected,
my image gets deformed and the scaled point is off :(

I'm trying to display the user current location (Lat, Lon) on a custom image (not a map image, a drawing of my own) therefor can't use maps (MKMapKit, Google, Tom-Tom).
I've have the user current location (via CoreLocation) and an image (800x460). the area that i'm mapping is small so i don't need to worry about the earth's curve.
For days now i'm trying to find a formula that'll help me scale my user (Lat, Lon) location into my image (on my iPhone screen).

Comment: Ooooh , ok , then you should get the map coordinates of the image area's corners in the first place. Then it will be simple to get the location inside that rectangle. Sorry , I didn't understand the goal at first

Comment: Cool :) BTW, i have the map coordinates (4 corners) of the area (Lat, Lon) in decimal values (not degrees).
I'm just having truble "translating" (or displaying) a random (Lat, Lon) point (x, y) to (or in) my image.
Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I think the same idea as the one in my answer applies. rect1 should be the rectangle of coordinates (lat , lon of your image and also the appropriate width & height meaning the width in lat points and height in lon points ) and rect2 should so something like `CGRectMake(0,0,yourImageWidth , yourImageHeight)`. Also , the point should mean the location of the user in rect1. So do something like `point.x -= rect1.origin.x;` and `point.y -= rect1.origin.y;` first , and then do the things I wrote in the answer. I think there was just a problem of good initial values.

Comment: One thing ...you can use this : `- (CGRect)convertRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region toRectToView:(UIView *)view` . Also be sure to take retina display into account *e.g. multiply the origin and size of the given rectangle by `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the distortions it introduces you can just treat `x`(`latitude`) and `y`(`longitude`) coordinates separately.

If you think you're not going to be happy with such distortions, what do you propose to do about the incommensurate scales in `latitude` and `longitude` ?  `1°lat != 1°long` in the latitudes in your question.

If you need help scaling from a line of one length to a line of another, update your question.

**EDIT** following comment by OP.

OK, so you want to map an interval of 3° in latitude to an interval of 300 pixels (I guess) in Y, and an interval of 6° in longitude to an interval of 500 pixels in X.

I'm still not entirely sure if you are concerned about introducing further distortions; if you're not it's very easy.  I'll suppose that the bottom left of your screen area is pixel (1,1) and that that is where you want to map (40°,56°) to.  For every minute of longitude east of that point, move `(500/360)` pixels to the right.  For every minute of latitude north of the corner, move `(300/180)` pixels up.

This rough-and-ready projection will not preserve the appearance of 2D shapes (for example a square will project to a rectangle) but there are many map projections in widespread use which do not preserve shapes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I've updated my question as you requested :)
Am i thinking right? Is this the right way?

Comment: oh...sorry but i meant Latitude and Longitude in decimal values and not degrees. I am very concerned about distortions, can't allow any.
For some reason i thought it's a matter of a single formula...guess i was wrong :) Thanks for your time!